# Fastest Way to Copy Buffer or C-String into a std::string

Tags: linux, gcc, c++11, stdstring

Let's say I have `char buffer[64]` and `uint32_t length`, and `buffer` might or might not be null terminated. If it is null terminated, the rest of the buffer will be filled with nulls. the `length` variable holds the length of buffer.

I would like to copy it into a `std::string` without extra nulls at the end of the string object.

Originally, I tried:

```
std::string s(buffer, length);
```

which copies the extra nulls when buffer is filled with nulls at the end.

I can think of:

```
char buffer2[128];
strncpy(buffer2, buffer, 128);
const std::sring s(buffer2);
```

But it is kind of wasteful because it copies twice.

I wonder whether there is a faster way. I know I need to benchmark to tell exactly which way is faster...but I would like to look at some other solutions and then benchmark...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you can, I'd simply add a `'\0'` at the end of your buffer and
   then use the c-string version of the `string` constructor.
2. If you can't, you need to determine if there's a `'\0'` in your
   buffer and while you're at it, you might as well count the number of
   characters you encounter before the `'\0'`. You  can then use that
   count with the `(buffer,length)` form of the `string` constructor:

   ```
   #include <string.h>
   //...   
   std::string s(buffer, strnlen(buffer, length));
   ```
3. If you can't do 1. and don't want to iterate over `buffer` twice (once to determine the length, once in the string constructor), you could do:

   ```
   char last_char = buffer[length-1];
   buffer[length-1] = '\0';
   std::string s(buffer);  //the c-string form since we're sure there's a '\0' in the buffer now
   if(last_char!='\0' && s.length()==(length-1)) {
   //With good buffer sizes, this might not need to cause reallocation of the strings internal buffer
        s.push_back(last_char); 
   }
   ```

   I leave the benchmarking to you. It is possible that the c-string version of the constructor    uses something like `strlen` internally anyway to avoid reallocations so there might not be much to gain from using the `c-string` version of the `string` constructor.

Comment: I can't add '\0' to the end unfortunately.  Your alternative solution is brilliant.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use all the canonical way to do this.

Faster way is surely implement by yourself **[smartpointer](http://ootips.org/yonat/4dev/smart-pointers.html)** (or use anything already done as [std::shared_ptr](http://it.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) 
).

Each smartpointer (sp) point to first char of array and contain.

Each time you do array.copy you don't do a true copy, but you simply add a reference do that array.

So, a "copy" take O(1) instead of O(N)